# How do Bind a key or mouse click to the fn key (autohotkey)

Tags: autohotkey

So I am working with an old windows vista and to decrease the volume you need to press fn + the up or down arrow key. I'm stuck trying to figure out how to find the key for the fn key but some of the methods I try don't work. I want to bind it to the mouse scroll, the normal soundset doesn't work for some reason the computer is an acser extenssa 5220. Anymore questions I will answer down bellow. I'm thinking about downloading a program to remap the keys on the vista, but then I still don't if that and autohotkey will work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't send the FN key because Windows doesn't actually even know of such a key. The FN key is processed by your keyboard. So what's sent to Windows is actually just the multimedia key, in your case volume up/down.

In AHK you can send the keys like this: [`SendInput, {Volume_Up}`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#keynames).
Alternatively you could use [`SoundSet`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundSet.htm).